# Christianity self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: Just to clarify, this _isn't_ the same criteria as the [other evaluation](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1068/914), right?

Comment: @Jon: Well, *I* evaluated these the same way.

Comment: Not to go all meta meta on you, but do we get to find out how SE's evaluation of the evaluations turns out?

Answer (score 7):

[Has the notion of "legitimacy" been abandoned in the Catholic Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/has-the-notion-of-legitimacy-been-abandoned-in-the-catholic-church)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Nothing embarrassing here. Easy to understand factual answer with references to official doctrine. It might benefit from more analysis and writeups, but since the OP seems to have been satisfied, it would be hard to say what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 6):

[Did Thomas actually touch Jesus's side?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7269/did-thomas-touch-jesuss-side)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 4):

[What was Paul's "revelation" (mentioned in Galatians 2:2)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/what-was-pauls-revelation-mentioned-in-galatians-22)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This looks solid. The question is a little bit squishy (doesn't provide any framework for judging answers) but the answer gives some concrete background and explains the reasoning for a specific conclusion. Somebody else with the same question should come away with some solid leads.

Answer (score 3):

[Does Abraham's Bosom (Hades/Paradise) still exist?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/abrahams-bosom-after-jesus)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question would be better if it specified which perspective (Catholic, Orthodox, Protestant) it was seeking.

Answer (score 3):

[How do Evangelicals celebrate Pentecost?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/how-do-evangelicals-celebrate-pentecost)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The answer that exists is good, but it could use much more comprehensive coverage. What various denominations/traditions have specific practices here?

Comment: If someone would just say, Evangelical's don't celebrate pentecost, Wikipedia is wrong or whatever, I'd have been more satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

[Counterarguments to "Numerology"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/counterarguments-to-numerology)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is not worded very clearly. The definition given for numerology is not accurate; a number can be understood to have a symbolic meaning outside of numerology. The answer is thorough, even if it doesn't precisely answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

[Why in the Book of Exodus did God let the people travel for exactly 40 years?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/why-in-the-book-of-exodus-did-god-let-the-people-travel-for-exactly-40-years)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This whole thing is pretty blah. This probably should have been a [hermeneutics.se] thing.

Comment: @Caleb: I thought your answer was very entertaining, however.

Answer (score 1):

[Non-movable feasts in the Lent and Easter seasons](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/non-movable-feasts-in-the-lent-and-easter-seasons)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: What is this even about?

Comment: I wasn't clear on what exactly was being asked. The answerer, though, seemed to understand. So maybe it's clear enough for people in the Orthodox and Catholic traditions, who would be most likely to be looking for this information.

Comment: On the plus side, the troll answer was deleted. ;-)

Comment: It was a hard question to search for since it was just speculation and I wanted help piecing together the reasoning behind parts of the Liturgical Calendar.  I was pretty satisfied with the Orthodox answer, but am holding out for a Catholic one.

Answer (score -1):

[How do schisms in the church fit into the plans of a monotheistic God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/how-do-schisms-in-the-church-fit-into-the-plans-of-a-monotheistic-god)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is good, but the answers leave me with the impression that the silt got stirred up but nothing really got clarified in the end. This is more of an impression than a detailed study of the content.

Comment: Oops.  I've been meaning to self-answer since my blog post was published.  But at the moment, @Caleb's impression about the answers seems correct to me.  I'm particular disappointed as I tried to provide constructive comments on each.

Answer (score -8):

[What is the Christian perspective on deceptive brain messages?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7305/what-is-the-christian-perspective-on-deceptive-brain-messages)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: As it currently stands, the question is meh; it's a bit hard to see what is actually being asked and the OP references a book that seems to be written by a "Christian Buddhist" of sorts. The corresponding answer is okay (especially for the question as it stands), but needs references. Hence, a -1.

Comment: I'm not even sure what is being asked. Is the OP looking for a book review, or for Bible verses addressing the book's topic, or something else entirely?